# Get classname of span where data-* is set as specific string

Tags: javascript, jquery, custom-data-attribute

I have some HTML which is displayed in one of two ways:

```
<div class="map-toggle">
   <span class="list-view-toggle" data-status="active">List</span>
   <span class="map-view-toggle" data-status="inactive">Map</span>
</div>
```

or

```
<div class="map-toggle">
   <span class="list-view-toggle" data-status="active">List</span>
   <span class="map-view-toggle" data-status="inactive">Map</span>
</div>
```

In one block, `.list-view-toggle` has a `data-status` attribute `active` and in the other it's `inactive` and vice versa for `.map-view-toggle`

I want to run some jQuery that simply finds which `span` in `.map-toggle` has the active class and console.log it for me.

```
var whichView = $('.map-toggle > span').attr('data-status','active').attr('class');
console.log(whichView);
```

So, in case of the first block being displayed on the page, `whichView` should return as `list-view-toggle`.

However I've discovered that it seems to be *applying* the data-status attribute `active` instead of locating and outputting in the variable. So it loads the page and makes BOTH spans `data-status="active"` which is obviously not what I'm after.

**How would I return the classname of only the active span in the shortest code possible?**

Comment: `.attr('data-status','active')` sets the attribute, not checks it....

Comment: `$('.map-toggle > span[data-status="active"]')`

Comment: @epascarello yes I'm aware, that's why I'm asking this question.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [attribute-selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/) of jQuery:

```
var whichView = $('.map-toggle > span[data-status="active"]').attr('class');
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/oty96efp/)**

Comment: But this is not jQuery but [css](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#matching-attrs), you can find some doc from [mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors)

Comment: FYI: attribute selector does not work all the time if data() is used.

Comment: @epascarello Yes this is worth mentioning. I was just relying on the information given. But when the status is set with `.data()` it would not be visible in the markup.

Answer (score 1):

Use `filter()` if the data attribute is being set with the `data()` method. Below shows both ways running in a little demo

```js
$(".map-toggle").on("click", "span", function () {
    $(this).data("status", "active").siblings().data("status", "inactive");
    test();
});



function test () {
    var whichView = $('.map-toggle > span')
                        .filter(function(){
                            return $(this).data("status") ==='active';
                        }).attr('class');
    console.log("filter way:" + whichView);
    //Other solution works on initial render, but fails when set with data().
    console.log("attribute way: " + $('.map-toggle > span[data-status="active"]').attr("class"));
}

test();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="map-toggle">
   <span class="list-view-toggle" data-status="active">List</span>
   <span class="map-view-toggle" data-status="inactive">Map</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to use following markup if possible as it makes everything easier and better understandable. You are also talking about classes, not attributes ([…]which span in .map-toggle has the active **class** […])

```
<div class="map-toggle">
    <span class="list-view-toggle active">List</span>
    <span class="map-view-toggle inactive">Map</span>
</div>
```

The selector you need than is:

```
$('.map-toggle > span.active')
```

Otherwise I like the @empiric’s solution.